# Python. Значение команд из bytecode

Tags: python

Что делает команда `LOAD_GLOBAL`?

```
30 39 LOAD_FAST 0 (arg)
42 LOAD_GLOBAL 0 (knock)
45 COMPARE_OP 2 (==)
48 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE 65
```

Есть ли какой-то источник, где внятно написано о том, как все работает?

Answer (score 2):

Официальная документация на модуль dis (https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) описывает эти команды.
PS.

> LOAD_GLOBAL(namei)
>       Loads the global named co_names[namei] onto the stack.

Comment: Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Тут нет примера решения, вопрос - поиск документации на систему команд виртуальной машины, объем информации - не одна сотня строк.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, об этом и речь в предыдущем комментарии. Было бы здорово, чтобы прочитав ответ, пользователь попавший на вопрос из поисковика, покинул сайт с какими-то новыми знаниями в голове. Просто ссылка не так эффективна, как ваше экспертное мнение по проблеме (то есть какие-то конкретные замечания, подкрепленные ссылкой на документацию).